# change the title for viewController into tabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionview

My App first view is UICollectionView and I push the Cell to TabBarController with five views but the problem when I change the title for each view didn't appear. So I need to put a different titles for these five viewController.

`CollectionView.m` is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    productName *data = [self.productarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imageView.image = data.productImage;

    UILabel *title2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    title2.text = data.productNames;

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ProductsViewController *detail = [[ProductsViewController alloc]init];
    //[self.view pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    detail.productNumber = indexPath.item;
    //NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.item);
}
```

Comment: Can you make the question clearer? What is your actual problem - the cells or the view controller not displaying the detail? Also are you subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` and creating a custom imageView and label?

Comment: My problem is i have the first viewController is uicollectionViewController and i pouch to tabbarViewController with five different viewController but i need to put different titles and itemBarButton to each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the tabBarController.  Something like this in your didSelect method. ...

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController * firstController = [[MYCustomViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarItem * firstItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:[UIImage imageNamed: @"FirstImage"] tag:1];
firstController.tabBarItem = firstItem;

//Now create second through fifth VCs here

tabBarController.viewControllers =  @[firstController, secondController, thirdController, fourthController, fifthController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

On the other hand, it's considered bad form (by Apple at least) to put a tab bar inside a navcontroller, and I don't think it's even possible to put a nav bar inside a nav bar.

Further thoughts (After comment below):

What I would suggest instead would be to "present" your tabBarController from your original collectionView, then each of the viewControllers inside the tab bar would be a navController. In your didSelect, this would now look like:

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *firstController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MYCustomViewController1 alloc] init];
UITabBarItem * firstItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:[UIImage imageNamed: @"FirstImage"] tag:1];
firstController.tabBarItem = firstItem;

//Now create second through fifth Nav VCs here

tabBarController.viewControllers =  @[firstController, secondController, thirdController, fourthController, fifthController];

tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To create a view (say MYView1) for a VC in Interface Builder (Edit>New>File>ios>UserInterface>View> and change File's OwnerType to the name of your VC class). Then  instead of just `[[MYCustomViewController1 alloc] init]` use `[[MYCustomViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYView1" bundle:nil]`

When you want to return from the tabBar back to the collectionView, from any of the embedded controllers, create a button and link its action to run this code:

```
[self.tabBarController dismissViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Finally, if you want to do ALL this in IB, just draw your tabcontroller with the associated five subcontrollers. Then have your `collectionViewController` (which should NOT be within a nav controller), and create a segue from your collectionViewCell to the tabController. Set the type of the segue to modal. Then clicking an item should launch the tabController directly. To set the productNumber information for the tabController, add this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender   {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   segue.destinationViewController.productNumber = indexPath.item;
}
```

Comment: put this code on didSelect method or create uitabbarcontroller class; please advice

Comment: Either way.  Either in didSelect, or (except for first and last line) in viewDidLoad in subclassed UITBC

Comment: i need to tell you that i have two navigation bar one for uitabbarcontroller and other for each view controller i have a navigationcontroller for each so i think the title shown for the tabbarcontroller navigationbar

Comment: Then see revised notes above.

Comment: can you told me where i put `[self.tabBarController dismissViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil]` on each viewDidload or where; second i use storyboard and the code working but allViews on storyBoard didn't shown; can you tell me what i can do for this

Comment: the dismiss is when you want to return. So if you have a Done button, that's the code that would return you to the collectionview.  Second, you can either build VCs/views visually in Interface Builder (storyboards) or in code; above is for code version, so your storyboard won't show that. On the other hand, you can still create a VC in IB and connect it in code, see revised note above.

Comment: you advice to cancel storyboard and go through xib file. that's right?

Comment: Not really. If you've already got a storyboard for your collection view, then you could EITHER add your tab controller and five sub controllers in storyboard, OR add your tab/subcontrollers in code (but still design the subcontrollers views in separate XIB files, if you like).

Comment: ok; but the code above we create fifth viewControllers different from what i already design on storyboard; so is it possible to match the code above with fifth viewController on storyboard or what can i should do?

Comment: Ok, then we've gone down the wrong path.  See above for doing this within Interface Builder.

Comment: when i hit the up arrow; told me you need 15 population; but really it;s very useful for me. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a [`UITabBarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBarItem) to the [`tabBarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarItem) property when you create your view controllers. If you just want a title you can just assign to the [`title`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) property.

```
UITableViewController *firstVC = ...
firstVC.title = @"Title";

UICollectionViewController *secondVC = ...
secondVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title2" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] tag:0];
```

Comment: My problem is i have the first viewController is uicollectionViewController and i pouch to tabbarViewController with five different viewController but i need to put different titles and itemBarButton to each

Comment: Where does the info for the 5 different tabs come from?

Comment: firstViewController is uitableViewController, secondViewController is uiCollectionViewController and the remaining is UIViewController. so i need to put different title for each and itemBarButton

Comment: sorry if i make disturb for you

Comment: No its fine, your question had item selection code in it and from the way it was originally worded it sounded like you wanted to change the title when you tapped on a cell :)